# How to decide about taking a job related to rather than directly in the field you are interested in?

Tags: software-industry, career-development, recruitment

I am asking this question for my wife:
She just finished her Master's degree in Computer Science and received a job offer as a business analyst for a banking business consulting company. The job entails requirement analysis and cost estimation for banking IT-processes. She seems to fit the profile, but is interested in working towards becoming an IT-project manager eventually. The contract conditions are good, so she does not want to lightly reject the offer.

I would be interested in knowing what factors to consider when deciding on a job offer that's in a related role to your ambitions.

Comment: @Myles While the question is no longer asking for highly-role-specific advice on what to do, it does seem awfully broad and/or under-specified now.

Comment: @Dukeling As per the SE philosophy "Death to the author".  Feel free to find the middle ground.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PM involves overseeing all aspects of the project.  Getting skills in one part will only help the overall ability of the PM to properly understand, budget, and manage the different parts.

Personally BA covers the scope and product alignment to the client needs.  I think this is a huge skill set that every PM needs at least a little experience with in order to properly do their job.  It's important to have experts, but if this is out of school and going into the field this will only strengthen her ability and references for becoming a PM.

*Note:* The issue comes when one stays extremely long in a very specific field and then wants to jump over.  So if she stays for 7-10 years as a BA and then wants to just jump into PM without training then her skills might be viewed as one sided, but it sounds more like she has solid schooling and is looking for experience, which if that is the case the BA is a solid move in that direction.  Get a couple years and then swap it up to PM or another role in the SDLC to round out the experience.

*P.S. I would check options at role rotations in the place the BA position is at.  It's better to get in the door and bounce to a few different roles than having to swap companies each time.*

Answer (score 0):

> I would be interested in knowing whether taking this job would curb or
>   conduce to her goal of becoming a project manager eventually.

It's not at all unusual for Business Analysts to become Project Managers over time.